# Single Linked Lists: Trying to remove element before a passed type Object paramater

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Ok, so I'm trying to make a method that takes as parameter an object, and removes the element before that one if it is found in the single linked list. My problem is when I am searching for the 2nd element. It follows the `if (i == 0)` but doesn't work and I'm not sure why. Can you please look at my code and tell me why it's not working?

main:

```
package SingleLinkedLists;

public class TestList {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SingleLinkedList testList = new SingleLinkedList();
    testList.insertLast(1);
    testList.insertLast(2);
    testList.insertLast(3);
    testList.insertLast(4);
    testList.insertLast(5);
    testList.print();
    System.out.println("This is what I'm taking out: " + testList.removeBefore(2));
    testList.print();
  }
}
```

method:

```
public Object removeBefore(Object o) {
  int i = 0;
  if (o == null)
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element");
  Node crt = head;
  Node prev = crt;
  // trying to find the element right before the parameter
  while(crt.next != null && !o.equals(crt.next.content)) {
    prev = crt;
    crt = crt.next;
    i++;
  }
  if (i == 0) {
    prev = crt.next;
    crt.next = null;
    return crt.content;
  }

  if (crt.next == null)
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element");

  // remove crt node from list
  prev.next = crt.next;
  crt.next = null;

  // return the removed content
  return crt.content;
}
```

output:

```
> run SingleLinkedLists.TestList
1
2
3
4
5
This is what I'm taking out: 1
1
>
```

output when using third element as passed parameter (3):

```
> run SingleLinkedLists.TestList
1
2
3
4
5
This is what I'm taking out: 2
1
3
4
5
>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you make a mistake.

When you remove the first element of your list, you should change the `head` to the second node. So you should write:

```
if (i == 0) {
    head = crt.next;
    return crt.content;
}
```